# Woocommerce swatches stacking (on top each other)

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I was not able to find woocommerce solution for stacking varation images on top of each other. I have images same resolution size which I don't want to merge with photoshop and looking to find plugin which would let me add it on top when selected. Only found example on shopify shop... https://onewheel.com/pages/customize-onewheel?Bumper=Black&Delete=Grey&Fender=Galaxy_Carbon&Footpad=Surestance_Pro_Max&Guard=Coral&Handle=Coral&Plug=--_No_Charger_Plug_--&Product=xr&Rail=Blue

Maybe you someone knows plugin which could help me?

Answer (score 0):

You might be looking for variable products, which should allow you to create different variation of the same product and apply different product image.

In the front end or in the actual product page, Woocommerce will automatically create a dropdown where you can select different variations. When a variation is selected, the product gallery will respond accordingly, and sdisplay the appropriate image or the image that is associated to the selected variation.

// https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/variable-product/

You can also use additional plugins to extend its functionality.

// https://wordpress.org/plugins/woo-variation-swatches/

Comment: But then it is just simple varation where you put color size etc and it shows final image. If you inspect the link I was looking for multiple images on top.